# Laravel 8 - Check in Controller if user has permission to call route

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have a class to create my navigation and i use spatie permissions. Now i want to build the navigation with the help of my defined routes. Is it possible to check if the User can access a route before to build a navigation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can able to check permission of users. Below are the methods available in spatie permissions.

```
$user->hasPermissionTo('edit articles');
```

You can check if a user has Any of an array of permissions:

```
$user->hasAnyPermission(['edit articles', 'publish articles', 'unpublish articles']);
```

...or if a user has All of an array of permissions:

```
$user->hasAllPermissions(['edit articles', 'publish articles', 'unpublish articles']);
```

You can refer [this link](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/basic-usage/direct-permissions)

$user is basically your auth()->user()

Comment: I realize that, but I already check the permissions in the web.php and would like to make it dependent for the navigation generation. Otherwise I would have to name the exact permissions there again.
`Route::resource('users', UserController::class)->middleware('auth')->middleware(['role:superadmin']);`

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Laravel 8.x version**.

We can check the given permission in `controller` file eg:

```
if(Auth::user()->can('product_view')){
    // allowed statement will be here
}
```

while given permission can be checked in `view` blade file eg:

```
@can('product_view')
    // allowed statement will be here
@endcan
```

We can also check permission in `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/products/productdetail', [ProductsController::class, 'productdetail'])->name('products.productdetail')->middleware('can:product_view');
```

Thanks a lot for asking this question. Happy to help :)